# Can't get 3d accel working in Ubuntu 17.04, Virtual Box. "Could not mount the media/drive ..." error

Tags: virtualbox, 17.04, 3d, hardware-acceleration

I'm following the directions [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/speed-up-ubuntu-virtualbox) and [in the related question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

I have run the following in my guest Ubuntu os:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential module-assistant dkms 
$ sudo m-a prepare
```

But the next direction, "In VirtualBox menu bar, select Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image." fails and gives me a popup with the message,

In VirtualBox menu bar, select Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image.

How do I fix this?